# Can download image, but can't view it

Tags: assets, image-path

We can download an image off our EE site, but the image doesn't display on the site itself. Any idea what could cause this? [image: cannot display image]

We're using EE 2.6.1.

Comment: Interesting, do you mean that the image does not display in the back end (the EE control panel) but it does display on the front end? What is the url of the broken link in your screenshot? Also what do the preferences for this file upload location look like.

Comment: Thanks for the response, mjr! We actually solved the issue yesterday. There was a internal redirect loop in our htaccess file that was taking valid URIs and returning 500s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually solved the issue yesterday. There was a internal redirect loop in our htaccess file that was taking valid URIs and returning 500s. Removed the loop, and images are now displaying as per usual.